# How can I transfer data from one route to another

Tags: node.js, express

I implement user registration. I have two routes.

```
import express from 'express';
import User from '../models/user';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    try {
    ...
        const user = new User(
            red.body.name,
            red.body.username,
            red.body.user_email,
            red.body.user_password,
            red.body.user_phone,
        );  
    ...
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            err: err
        });
    }
});

router.post('/verify', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        ...
        console.log(user);
        ...
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            err: err
        });
    }
});
```

I need to send data from the route, user registration, to the route, user confirmation.

How to send user data to the second route for confirmation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 strategies to implement this feature (maybe more):

**Strategy 1: Store `user` in server.**

You can store `user` object and assign it a unique key (e.g. uuid) in server. The `user` data can be stored as global variable (in memory of Node.js process), or it can be stored in memory database (e.g. Redis) if you are using multiple Node.js process.

In `POST /signup` route handler, the `user` data can be written to server, and this newly created user id would be returned to browser. Then, in `POST /verify` route handler, server would retrieve corresponding user data via its id.

**Strategy 2: Store `user` in browser.**

Another strategy is returning the whole `user` data to browser in `POST /signup` route handler, and let browser send it back in the following `POST /verify` request. There are 2 ways to implement this design (maybe more):

- Return `user` data to browser via `Set-Cookie`. Browser would send user data as cookie automatically.
- Return `user` data to browser as plain response body. Browser take it and save it in localStorage or sessionStorage. Then, when sending `POST /verify` request, browser would read that data and put it as plain HTTP request body.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this would be to store the user data as a browser cookie. Storing user data in local storage is not recommended as it can be accessed by JavaScript and hence poses a security threat.